# Finding out the length AB

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In the following picture we can see a equilateral triangle of length l. How to find the length of AB?

Is the A is center of  mass of the triangle, therefore we can divide it 2:1 ?

The answer is given by $\frac{l}{\sqrt{3}}$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you know trigonometry? Let D be mid-point of mB.

$ DB / AB = \cos 30{^0} = \sqrt {3}/2. $